# Defining a data-type (single-property class) that does not require an accessor

Tags: c#, types, properties, accessor

In my project I have some float fields that should stay in a range of 0-1. If possible, I would like to have a custom data-type, call it float01, that simply clamps the value whenever it is written to, so that I don't have to remember to do so every time. That way I can simply write:

```
float01 clampedFloat = .9f;
```

I could make a new class for this, with a single property that has a custom setter to take care of the clamping, but then I always need to refer to it by its accessor:

```
clampedFloat.Value += .2f;
```

Is there any way to define a custom data-type where I can simply write the following?

```
clampedFloat += .2f;
```

I know it looks like a small thing here, but if I have to add the accessor every time, I might as well just clamp it every time instead. More than that, it feels like I'm missing something, like it should be easy to add a simple data-type without the required fluff that class properties have.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have a look at [defining a struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) and then [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should be easy to add a simple data-type without the required fluff that class properties have.

To define your own type or struct you can use [custom conversion operators](http://should%20be%20easy%20to%20add%20a%20simple%20data-type%20without%20the%20required%20fluff%20that%20class%20properties%20have.) and even more advanced stuff like [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading).

**[Custom conversion](http://should%20be%20easy%20to%20add%20a%20simple%20data-type%20without%20the%20required%20fluff%20that%20class%20properties%20have.)**
To convert your new cool class to or from another class you need to use conversion operators.

For this you follow a simple format

To convert from a type

```cs
public static implicit operator <YOUR_TYPE>(<OTHER_TYPE> obj)
```

To convert TO a type

```cs
public static implicit operator <OTHER_TYPE>(<YOUR_TYPE>obj)
```

Here's a quick and simple example that might help you out.

```cs
public class ClampedFloat
{
    public float Min { get; set; } = -1f;
    public float Max { get; set; } = 1f;

    public float Value
    {
        get => _Value;
        set
        {
            _Value = Math.Clamp(value, Min, Max);
        }
    }

    private float _Value = 0f;

    public static implicit operator float(ClampedFloat obj)
    {
        return obj.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator ClampedFloat(float obj)
    {
        return new ClampedFloat() { Value = obj };
    }
}
```